# spring security failed - error 403

Tags: tomcat, authentication, spring-security, virtual-machine

I have installed a BackEnd(spring,spring security...)/Frontend(angularjs, bootstrap) application on a remote server (tomcat on a VM).

One time per day, i don't know why, when i want to login, i have message : 
`username or password incorrect`
Of course, i'm sure of the id and pwd.

The only solution i found is to stop and restart my tomcat.
I don't understand if problem comes from VM, Tomcat or spring-security

this is my spring-security config files :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-2.0.xsd">

<http create-session="stateless" use-expressions="true" entry-point-ref="customAuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <intercept-url pattern="/api/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
    <remember-me key="remember-me-security" services-ref="rememberMeServices" />
    <form-login
        authentication-success-handler-ref="customAuthenticationSuccessHandler "
        authentication-failure-handler-ref="customAuthenticationFailureHandler " />
    <logout success-handler-ref="customLogoutSuccessHandler"/>

</http>

<beans:bean id="rememberMeServices" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices">
    <beans:property name="userDetailsService" ref="customUserDetailService"/>
    <beans:property name="key" value="remember-me-security"/>
    <beans:property name="cookieName" value="X-XSRF-TOKEN" />
    <beans:property name="tokenValiditySeconds" value="3600" />
    <!-- <property name="parameter" value="remember-me-parameter"/> -->
</beans:bean>

<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="customUserDetailService">
        <password-encoder hash="sha-256">
            <!-- <salt-source user-property="nom"/> -->
        </password-encoder>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager> 

<global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" pre-post-annotations="enabled"/>
```

Moreover, i have a problem explained in tomcat logs :

```
  févr. 04, 2015 9:20:11 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve    invoke
   SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [rest] in context with path     [/FrancoFormInscrip-0.1] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException:   Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.TransactionException: JDBC begin transaction failed: ] with root cause
  java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error
   at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:109)
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:153)
at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.send(MysqlIO.java:3969)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2598)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2778)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2819)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.setAutoCommit(ConnectionImpl.java:5346)
at     org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.doBegin(JdbcTransaction.java:72)
at    org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.begin(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:160)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1426)
at org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:59)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.DefaultJpaDialect.beginTransaction(DefaultJpaDialect.java:71)
at    org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.beginTransaction(HibernateJpaDialect.java:61)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:378)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:372)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:417)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:255)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:91)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:631)
at com.mc.jci.ff.service.InscriptionService$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$b5c63e29.init(<generated>)
at com.mc.jci.ff.controller.InscriptionController.init(InscriptionController.java:35)
at com.mc.jci.ff.controller.InscriptionController$$FastClassByCGLIB$$4c0739a7.invoke(<generated>)
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:698)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.CustomizableTraceInterceptor.invokeUnderTrace(CustomizableTraceInterceptor.java:257)
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.AbstractTraceInterceptor.invoke(AbstractTraceInterceptor.java:111)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:91)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:631)
at com.mc.jci.ff.controller.InscriptionController$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$f582d2ce.init(<generated>)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor190.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter.handle(CrossOriginFilter.java:247)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter.doFilter(CrossOriginFilter.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:999)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:565)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:309)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Can it be linked ?

Comment: I think your question is impossible to answer with the currently given information. Consider do some debugging, and try to narrow the problem down some, and give us some code snippet or something to look at.

Comment: Hi mattias, i have just a log in tomcat "localhost_acces_log" file : [02/Feb/2015:08:48:44 +0100] "POST /FrancoFormBackEnd-0.1/j_spring_security_check HTTP/1.1" 403 970. How to get more ?

Comment: i have also in chrome console : "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Interdit)". But of course if i stop and start tomcat, it works...i don't understand